# Find the third point of an equilateral triangle given first two

Tags: trigonometry

Find the third point of an equilateral triangle given first two?
I have `p1 (x1, y2)` and `p2 (x2, y2)`, best way to find `p3 (x3, y3)` that makes up the equilateral triangle formed by these points?

So the best way I can think of is to

1. find the angle of line p1 and p2.
2. add 90(degree) to the angle.
3. calculate the point p3 that is in the new direction starting from the midpoint of p1 and p2 with length ${\sqrt{3}}/2$.

Is there a better (shorter) way to find p3?

Comment: You have too much information.  The side length is already determined by the two points.

Comment: yup :D .. realized after I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a Cartesian coordinate system with $A(-x_1,0)$ and $$B(x_1;0)$$ and the side length of the triangle given by $a$: Then we get
$$x_1^2+h^2=a$$ and we can compute the hight $h$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  In an equilateral triangle, the altitude is exactly $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ times as long as the side length, and it meets the base at exactly its midpoint.

As such, take $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$.  Its midpoint is $M(\frac{x_1+x_2}2,\frac{y_1+y_2}2)$.  We want to find $C(x,y)$ such that $|CM|=\frac{\sqrt3}2|AB|$ and $CM\perp AB$.

---

Alternatively, if you have a compass, simply draw two circles with a radius equal to the given line segment, centered at each end of the line segment.  The third point is the intersection of the two circles (there are two solutions).

Comment: So the best way I can think of is to calculate angle between p1 and p2. Add 90 (degress) to it. Then calculate p3 (starting from midpoint) in the new direction with sqrt3/2 length? That is the best i could think of ... is there a faster way to calculate this (in terms of machine operations)?